# Cloud solution to parse and process 1M+ rows

Tags: parsing, lambda, bigdata, distributed-system, system-design

We are writing a service that can parse a CSV file containing over 1M+ rows. Each row needs insertion (or update) data of a DB record. We are currently using DynamoDB.

What AWS services are best suited for this? We are considering lambda and queue system.

---

---

Solution we are looking at.

1. **API**: An API would accept the csv file upload. The API would go through the file and start reading it in chunks. Each chunk would be pushed to a queue for processing.
2. **QUEUE**: The queue holds chunks of the original file as a message to be processed.
3. **PROCESSOR**: The chunk processor goes through the queue and inserts records to dynamo.

### [image]

**Challenges**:

- How would you trigger an end of processing notification (to indicate the last chunk for that request was completed).
- How would you handle partial failure and rollback if using this approach?

Comment: Seems like a good fit for a MapReduce type of tool such as hadoop, spark, etc.

Comment: Both the challenges you mentioned are already solved by systems like spark/ hadopp.